# Angular2 variable in service not updating

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-services

I have a component with a conditional class. A sibling component has an click event that passes `true` to a service function. The function is triggered but the value isn't updated in the sibling to activate the class:

html:

```
<div class="location-details flyout" ng-class="{'active': flyoutState}">
    ...
</div>
```

flyout.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FlyoutService } from './flyout.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-flyout',
  templateUrl: './flyout.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./flyout.component.scss']
})
export class FlyoutComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  flyoutState: Boolean;

  constructor(private flyoutservice: FlyoutService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.flyoutservice.flyoutActive.subscribe(flyoutState => this.flyoutState = flyoutState);
...
  }

}
```

map.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FlyoutService } from '../flyout/flyout.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-map',
  templateUrl: './map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map.component.scss']
})
export class MapComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

    flyoutState: Boolean;


  constructor(private flyoutservice: FlyoutService) { 

  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {

    this.flyoutservice.flyoutActive.subscribe(flyoutState => this.flyoutState = flyoutState);

      let mapFlyoutService = this.flyoutservice;

      function stationClick(l, i, s) {
        /*
        console.log(l); // locaiton
        console.log(i); // id
        console.log(s); // siblings w/ data
        */

          mapFlyoutService.changeFlyoutState(!this.flyoutActive);

      }
  }

}
```

flyout.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class FlyoutService {
  private flyoutState = new BehaviorSubject(false);
  flyoutActive = this.flyoutState.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  changeFlyoutState(flyoutState: Boolean) {
    this.flyoutState.next(flyoutState);
    console.log(flyoutState);
  }

}
```

Note that if I don't do this `let mapFlyoutService = this.flyoutservice;` and use `this.flyoutservice` in the `stationClick()` function it says `flyoutservice` is undefined. Not sure if the `myFlyoutService` is the issue.

You'll notice I'm attempting to just flip the value between true/false with this `mapFlyoutService.changeFlyoutState(!this.flyoutActive);` but it always logs `true` meaning the initial state of `false` never gets updated.

Also, the class never gets added. That function should turn the class "on and off" but is has no effect.

Answer (score 2):

```
  stationClick(l, i, s) => {
    /*
    console.log(l); // locaiton
    console.log(i); // id
    console.log(s); // siblings w/ data
    */

      this.flyoutservice.changeFlyoutState(!this.flyoutActive);

  }
```

Use the es6 way of writing functions, it will preserve the scope, inside the function when you use `this` it gets the `window` scope rather than the `component` scope. The window doesn't have any `flyoutActive` property. so `!undefined` is always `true`. This is also the reason why `this.flyoutservice` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

`ng-class` is AngularJS style

Use `ngClass` instead

Also avoid calling functions that may change the UI in AfterViewInit hook

Comment: The content being changed is loaded dynamically, using `OnInit` doesn't work.

Comment: see @AshishRanjan answer, and use `OnInit` really. every async operation triggers change detection then it totally fits your needs